# How to create a form in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using the Javascript API (ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.40). But I can't find a way how I can add a form that allows me to enter Latitude and Longitude where I mark the point on the map. The example I am using is "Add graphics to a map".
URL: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/graphics_add.html

Code from Arcgis page:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Shapes and Symbols</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.40/esri/css/esri.css">

    <style>
      #info {
        top: 20px;
        color: #444;
        height: auto;
        font-family: arial;
        right: 20px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 115px;
        z-index: 40;
        border: solid 2px #666;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      html, body, #mapDiv {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
      }
      button {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.40/"></script>
    <script>
      var map, tb;

      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/toolbars/draw",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/PictureFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/CartographicLineSymbol", 
        "esri/graphic", 
        "esri/Color", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, Draw,
        SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        PictureFillSymbol, CartographicLineSymbol, 
        Graphic, 
        Color, dom, on
      ) {
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          basemap: "topo-vector",
          center: [-25.312, 34.307],
          zoom: 2
        });
        map.on("load", initToolbar);

        // markerSymbol is used for point and multipoint, see http://raphaeljs.com/icons/#talkq for more examples
        var markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
        markerSymbol.setPath("M16,4.938c-7.732,0-14,4.701-14,10.5c0,1.981,0.741,3.833,2.016,5.414L2,25.272l5.613-1.44c2.339,1.316,5.237,2.106,8.387,2.106c7.732,0,14-4.701,14-10.5S23.732,4.938,16,4.938zM16.868,21.375h-1.969v-1.889h1.969V21.375zM16.772,18.094h-1.777l-0.176-8.083h2.113L16.772,18.094z");
        markerSymbol.setColor(new Color("#00FFFF"));

        // lineSymbol used for freehand polyline, polyline and line. 
        var lineSymbol = new CartographicLineSymbol(
          CartographicLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
          new Color([255,0,0]), 10, 
          CartographicLineSymbol.CAP_ROUND,
          CartographicLineSymbol.JOIN_MITER, 5
        );

        // fill symbol used for extent, polygon and freehand polygon, use a picture fill symbol
        // the images folder contains additional fill images, other options: sand.png, swamp.png or stiple.png
        var fillSymbol = new PictureFillSymbol(
          "images/mangrove.png",
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color('#000'), 
            1
          ), 
          42, 
          42
        );

        function initToolbar() {
          tb = new Draw(map);
          tb.on("draw-end", addGraphic);

          // event delegation so a click handler is not
          // needed for each individual button
          on(dom.byId("info"), "click", function(evt) {
            if ( evt.target.id === "info" ) {
              return;
            }
            var tool = evt.target.id.toLowerCase();
            map.disableMapNavigation();
            tb.activate(tool);
          });
        }

        function addGraphic(evt) {
          //deactivate the toolbar and clear existing graphics 
          tb.deactivate(); 
          map.enableMapNavigation();

          // figure out which symbol to use
          var symbol;
          if ( evt.geometry.type === "point" || evt.geometry.type === "multipoint") {
            symbol = markerSymbol;
          } else if ( evt.geometry.type === "line" || evt.geometry.type === "polyline") {
            symbol = lineSymbol;
          }
          else {
            symbol = fillSymbol;
          }

          map.graphics.add(new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol));
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div id="info">
      <div>Select a shape then draw on map to add graphic</div>
      <button id="Point">Point</button>
      <button id="Multipoint">Multipoint</button>
      <button id="Line">Line</button>
      <button id="Polyline">Polyline</button>
      <button id="FreehandPolyline">Freehand Polyline</button>
      <button id="Triangle">Triangle</button>
      <button id="Extent">Rectangle</button>
      <button id="Circle">Circle</button>
      <button id="Ellipse">Ellipse</button>
      <button id="Polygon">Polygon</button>
      <button id="FreehandPolygon">Freehand Polygon</button>
    </div>

    <div id="mapDiv"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to develop a custom widget? or you just want a simple form on the example you post?.

Comment: Hi @cabesuon It is more the second question, I want to take the Arcgis example that has the buttons to add points, but the modification or the new thing is to add a form that asks for longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example I put for you, that I am guessing could help you in your task,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Add Lat Lon Points</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.40/esri/css/esri.css">

    <style>
        #info {
            top: 20px;
            color: #444;
            height: auto;
            font-family: arial;
            right: 20px;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            z-index: 40;
            border: solid 2px #666;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #mapDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        input, button, label {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 5px;
        }
        input, label {
            width: 180px;
            margin: 5px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        button {
            width: 190px;
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.40/"></script>
    <script>
        var map, tb;

        require([
            "esri/map",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
            "esri/graphic",
            "esri/geometry/Point",
            "esri/Color",
            "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (
            Map,
            SimpleMarkerSymbol,
            Graphic,
            Point,
            Color,
            dom,
            on
        ) {
            const map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                basemap: "topo-vector",
                center: [-25.312, 34.307],
                zoom: 2
            });
            map.on("load", function() {
                // markerSymbol is used for point, see http://raphaeljs.com/icons/#talkq for more examples
                const markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
                markerSymbol.setPath("M16,4.938c-7.732,0-14,4.701-14,10.5c0,1.981,0.741,3.833,2.016,5.414L2,25.272l5.613-1.44c2.339,1.316,5.237,2.106,8.387,2.106c7.732,0,14-4.701,14-10.5S23.732,4.938,16,4.938zM16.868,21.375h-1.969v-1.889h1.969V21.375zM16.772,18.094h-1.777l-0.176-8.083h2.113L16.772,18.094z");
                markerSymbol.setColor(new Color("#00FFFF"));

                on(dom.byId("addButton"), "click", function (evt) {
                    const long = dom.byId("longInput").value;
                    const lat = dom.byId("latInput").value;
                    if (!long || !lat) {
                        return;
                    }
                    const pto = new Point(long, lat);
                    map.graphics.add(new Graphic(pto, markerSymbol));
                    map.centerAt(pto);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="info">
        <label>
            Long <input type="number" id="longInput"/>
        </label>
        <label>
            Lat <input type="number" id="latInput"/>
        </label>
        <button id="addButton">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I will though recommend you to use the newest version of the library. At this point I believe the only reason to do any development in 3.x version is to support already build applications or sites.